# How to store database records into hash ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm using mysql database.
Now I want to retrieve data from my database: value and time, for plotting graph.
my db store up to 4000 data,and I need plot 1000 of them.

First method come to my mind is:

```
points=Hash.new
Records.all.each do |record|
  points[record.time.to_s]=record.value.to_s
end
```

then cut the first 1000 records.

But this way will be very inefficient and time consuming,It will cause my web load long.

I feel there must be a efficient way of doing this?
convert first 1000 database records's attributes into hash?
or convert to array pairs also ok for me,as long as data pair can plot.

thanks!

Comment: try using `Record.find_each do |record|` and use `limit` to fetch 1000 number of records

Comment: Do you mean `points[user.time.to_s] = record.value.to_s`?  And is `user.time.to_s` supposed to be the same for every `record`?

Comment: sorry typo error should be: points[record.time.to_s]=record.value.to_s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
data = Record.limit(1000)          # Load no more than a 1000 entries
             .pluck(:time, :value) # Pick the field values into sub-arrays
                                   # it will also `SELECT` only these two
# At this point you have [[time1, value1], [time2, value2]]
# good already, but we can go further:
             .to_h # Ruby 2.1+ only! I hope you're up-to-date!
# Now it is {time1 => value1, time2 => value2}
```

Comment: Very nice. Note `.to_h` isn't in Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [limit](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset):

```
points = Record.limit(1000).map { |r| { r.time => r.value } }
```